# static files routes in node express not working

Tags: node.js, express

I there,

I have search for an answer to what seems to be my problem, and I have made the implementation that can be found in the answers related to my problem, but they are not working.

dev machine: windows 10 pro
packages installed:

```
 "express": "^4.16.3",
  "request": "^2.87.0",
  "serve-static": "^1.13.2",
```

dir folders

```
|app
| |- web
| |  |-pages
| |  |   - <app domain folder>
| |  |    |  - index.html
| |  |    |- routeHandler.js    
| |  |-static
| |  | - js
| |  |   | - appClient.ls
|infrascruture
| - web
| | -builder.js 
|index.js
```

on the buider.js I have all the express boilerplate code to start the server including the static middleware:
like this:

```
var serveStatic = require("serve-static");

module.exports = (function(express)
{
module = {};
module.webApp =  express();

module.addAppComponents = function() {}
module.addStaticMiddleware = function()
{
 module.webApp.use('static', serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "/app/web/static/js/")));
}
return module;
});
```

on the index.js on the root of the application I'm calling the addStaticMiddleware() from an instance of that module.

the index.html on the app domain folder is served to a route that is working and the html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="/static/clientApp.js" ></script> 
    <body onload="loaded()">
        <h1> Endpoints</h1>
        <h2> These are the endpoints available to subscribe</h2>
    </body>

</html>
```

and the  index.html associated to a route previous registered is being correctly rendered on the client but the javascript is not being fetch:

the requests that the browser is doing are:

```
// fetching the index.html
request: GET url: localhost:8080/pages/endpoints/{}
headers: {"host":"localhost:8080","connection":"keep-alive","cache-control":"max-age=0","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"}
body: "{}"

// fetching the javascript but not working
request: GET url: localhost:8080/static/clientApp.js{}
headers: {"host":"localhost:8080","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://localhost:8080/pages/endpoints/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"}
```

any thoughts ?

thks in advance!

Comment: Well i think i figured out ... i miss understood the __dirname value. the value of this global variable represents the path to the current module and not the application root.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
module.webApp.use('static', serveStatic('../../app/web/static/js/')));
```

instead of

`module.webApp.use('static', serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "/app/web/static/js/")));`

Comment: The solution that I came up to this problem was to maintain the root dir in a object that preserves properties to be shared across the entire application. The problem with your solution is that you are fixing the relativity of your path, witch is something that I want to avoid.